# Añadir elementos no repetidos en un ArrayList en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo un ArrayList de empleados con atributos: String nombre, double sueldo.
Los valores se insertan por teclado a través de una única linea.
No puede haber valores repetidos y no se como hacerlo ya que el código me da error cuando añado mas de 2 empleados. El ejercicio se tiene que resolver con ArrayList.
Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestras respuestas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);
    int cantidad = 5;
    ArrayList <Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList <>();
    String cadena = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i<cantidad; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca datos: ");
        cadena = leer.nextLine();
        
        //separar cadena por espacios en blanco.
        String [] cortarString = cadena.split("\\s");
        
        //se añade el primer elemento en el ArrayList
        if (i == 0) { 
            Empleado empleado = new Empleado("",0);
            empleado.setNombre(cortarString [0]);
            empleado.setSueldo(Double.parseDouble(cortarString [1]));
            listaEmpleados.set(empleado);
            
        }else {// para los siguientes elementos se va comparando los valores del nombre

            //bucle para recorrer el ArrayList listaEmpleado
            for (int j = 0; j<listaEmpleados.size(); j++) {
                //Si existe no lo añade
                if (cortarString[0].equalsIgnoreCase(listaEmpleados.get(j).getNombre())) {
                    System.out.println("El empleado ya existe");
                }else {
                    Empleado empleado = new Empleado("",0);
                    empleado.setNombre(cortarString [0]);
                    empleado.setSueldo(Double.parseDouble(cortarString [1]));
                    listaEmpleados.set(empleado);;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Deberías de especificar el error que te sale

Comment: Errores aparte, tu planteamiento tiene un problema. En el momento en que el nombre introducido sea diferente del primer elemento de la lista, vas a insertarlo. Imaginemos esta lista de nombres `{"Pedro", "Jose", "María"}`, si intentas añadir a `"Jose"` de nuevo, entras a tu bucle -> Compruebas si el nombre es diferente del primer elemento: `"Jose" != "Pedro"` -> entramos al else y añadimos a `"Jose"`... MEEEEEC, error. Jose ya existe en la lista, simplemente no es el primero... necesitas usar un *flag* para determinar si existe o no **AL SALIR DEL BUCLE** y **NO DENTRO**!

Comment: Código mal organizado, todo metido dentro del mismo bloque, ese es el principal problema que hace que pronto te encuentres perdido en tu propio programa. Te recomiendo que crees un método para verificar la existencia del eventual nuevo elemento del array, desde ese método retornas un booleano, en el caso de que exista, lo retornas de inmediato, no tienes que seguir recorriendo todo el array, y no insertas ese elemento, porque ya existe.

Comment: Solucionado!! Cree un metodo comprobarEmpleado que me devuelve un booleano existe. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: te recomiendo investigar el metodo [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) de clase ArrayList

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba con esto

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class run {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cantidad = 5;
    ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleados = new ArrayList<>();
    String cadena = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca datos: ");
        cadena = leer.nextLine();

        //separar cadena por espacios en blanco.
        String[] cortarString = cadena.split("\\s");


        //se añade el primer elemento en el ArrayList
        if (i == 0) {
            Empleado empleado = new Empleado("", 0);
            empleado.setNombre(cortarString[0]);
            empleado.setSueldo(Double.parseDouble(cortarString[1]));
            listaEmpleados.add(empleado);

        } else {// para los siguientes elementos se va comparando los valores del nombre

            boolean repetido = false;
            int j = 0;
            while (!repetido && j < listaEmpleados.size()) {

                repetido = Objects.equals(cortarString[0], listaEmpleados.get(j).getNombre());
                System.out.println(listaEmpleados.get(j).getNombre());
                j++;
            }
            if (repetido) {
                System.out.println("El empleado ya existe");
            } else {
                Empleado empleado2 = new Empleado(cortarString[0], Double.parseDouble(cortarString[1]));
                listaEmpleados.add(empleado2);
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Hice algo parecido y funcionó

Comment: me alegro mucho  :)